# C2440 error when using Qt creator but code runs fine using VS2010 Express

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, qt

I have these lines of code in a command line project in VS2010 c++.

```
        TCHAR          name[30];
        LPTSTR         pname=&name[0];
        std::wstring   OutNumber;
        pname = &name[0];
        GetWindowText(hGameNumber,pname,30);
```

works fine without problems.
No I'm using the same lines in a Qt widget base application using Qt Creator. When compiling it I get the error:

"error: C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from 'TCHAR *' to 'LPTSTR'
Types pointed to are unrelated; conversion requires reinterpret_cast, C-style cast or function-style cast"

Thanks for any help, Lumpi

Comment: `LPTSTR` is supposed to be a typedef for `TCHAR *`. If it isn't on your system, something's wrong. Could you include a full program that fails, and include details on how exactly you're compiling it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

cast, as in
     `LPTSTR pname = reinterpret_cast<LPTSTR>(&name[0]);`

and all will be well. also remove the line that reads
`pname = &name[0];` right after you  create the std::wstring object.

Comment: That all depends on which compiler QT is using to compile the code (via gcc-mingw, or what not)

Comment: @hvd he could just use a (LPTSTR) cast and really put himself in the whole "I know what I'm doing" mood with the compiler. I don't suspect he's anything more than someone exploring the language trying to learn it. Besides, it's not like he's trying to cast Foo to a Bar to begin with. the underlying types in the windows.h file are the same, at least when it's a real windows.h file and not the one that's included in the gcc-mingw suite. It's rather different.

Comment: @both I just thought of that to, in VS in know where to set UNICODE in the project options. I guess I should do that in Qt to, IÄll just have to figure out where...

Comment: @hvd have you ever used mingw? I have. It doesn't break badly at all. The underlying type that TCHAR is selected is both the same in mscv and mingw, it's just how the header that comes with mingw goes about doing it vs the way the regular windows sdk header goes about doing it is a tad different, because they are meant for different compilers.

Comment: @hdv delve into the headers for each, msvc(windows sdk, winnt.h) and mingw (winnt.h) and see the difference for your self , and you'll see why the mingw requires the cast ;)

Comment: @hdv but they don't bro, check widdows sdk winnt.h. compare it to mingw's winnt.h

Comment: @hdv it's not like that in windows the windows sdk bro.

Comment: Now, the way it's tpedef'd , DOES matter. Hence the need for the cast. Furthermore inserting the cast into the op's code, makes it more neutral for use in QT to begin with, in either case of compiler. The fact that I've had to go on this long discussion with you in comments is rather bothersome. The underlying problem is that one header typedef'd something different than the way another did, the resulting underlying type is the same, but the compilers see different types when looking at the result type. Which makes it safe to cast to begin with.

Comment: @hvd mingw (in my experience) does not always accept it without a cast to begin with. In fact my fist experience of having to cast the types mentioned was WITH mingw. QT Creator defaults to using and OLD version of mingw at that.

Comment: I'm compiling using MSVC2010, not mingw.

Comment: @Lumpi In fact, I'll go and remove my comments here, they do nothing to help you with your problem. Best of luck trying to figure out what's actually going on.